# Netbeans Source Format: Can It Recognize Other Stuff? (For RoR Views)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, netbeans

I am in love with Netbeans Source->Format feature. Is there any way to get it to recognize stuff in these blocks

```
<% content_for :style do %>

<% end %>
```

as CSS? It would also help for autocomplete.

Ditto, of course, for

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
<% end %>
```

blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think the source formatting is on a file basis only, not on parts of a file.

**Edit**: Actually, I'm wrong, the formatting can recognize various languages in the same file...obviously what's happening in an ERB file for ruby and html code. But I don't see a way of extending that.

Comment: Really? I kind of though this was either easy or that my question would get closed as "not programming related" :)  I'll have to dig into it soon, I really hope there's a positive answer. It does recognize CSS and javascript in an HTML file, which you mention (well, with ERB there are four languages happening). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Best answer just because I cannot delete the question :)